# How do i rotate my character head without deforming the neck like that?

Tags: mesh, rigging, bones, pose-mode

I'm using Blender 2.79 and I've been trying to fix this, and i can't get my character head to rotate without messing up the neck. I tried with one bone, two bones and three, i've tried adding some Inverse kinematics to see if i could get a better result but nothing. here is the file: https://www.mediafire.com/file/4wvs3tf5f3e4pqx/Meajuda.blend/file

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, it seems normal that it deforms the neck, maybe describe more in detail what you're trying to avoid, do you want the deformation to be smooth and more progressive etc? Also I'm not sure that the direction of the neck bones make sense, shouldn't they go up rather than down?

Comment: I wanted the character to be able to rotate his head like a deer does, without pulling the mesh like that, and the bones are like that but it doesn't make difference, i made and re-made the bones and tried to rotate it, but it pushes the mesh and make it thin around the head... example picture: https://img.artpal.com/31643/2-15-4-10-11-46-43m.jpg

Comment: Actually I wonder if you should not use bendy bones and Stretch To constraint for this kind of rigging: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5YT3Ocxeawo

Comment: You could potentially use Bone Constraints to Copy Rotation along the neck - so when you rotate the head the other bones also rotate, but with reduced influence such that they only rotate a fraction of the head. This way the rest of the mesh will follow with reduced twist. I'll try and put together an example. The other solution woudl be to use Weight Paint to add influence from the head bone to other parts of the mesh to smooth out the twist - but that's probably a lot more manual work.